# How can a JS Client pass POST parameters to a JS Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, command-line-interface

I'd like to have a pair of Javascript client and server that communicate
using JSON without involving a Web Browser. I can get it going as long as
the client does not try to send anything to the server. When it does, I get
the error message (% node poster.js):

```
.../node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:281
            throw new NetworkError(`Unsupported protocol ${this._url.protocol}`);
```

Can somebody help me with this protocol issue please. What I have so far:
a server that I can start with "pm2 start jsonServer.js" -

```
var port = 62022
var http = require('http')
var srvr = http.createServer (function (req, res) {
        console.log ('Request type: ' + typeof(req))
        console.log (req)
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('Hello World!\n');
        res.write(req);
        res.end();
})
var scriptName = __filename.split(__dirname+"/").pop();
console.log ('Script: ' + scriptName +'. Listening to port ' + port)
srvr.listen(port)
```

... and a client that is

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2')

var serialize = function(object) {
  return JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)
}

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "localhost:62022");

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onload = () => console.log(xhr.responseText);

let data = `{
  "Id": 912,
  "First Name": "Archibald",
  "Last Name": "Haddock"
}`;
//console.log (serialize(data));
//xhr.send(serialize(data));
console.log (data);
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: xhr.open doesn't include a protocol.  Try `xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:62022")`

Answer (score 0):

This is what is needed after posting 'Hello World!' on the server (res.end does not wait for the async data transfer):

```
        let data = '';
        req.on('data', chunk => {
                data += chunk;
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
                // do whatever with data
                res.write ('Data: ' + data + '\n')
                res.end()
        });
```